# Heading with line afterwards, with 2 different sizes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following, with pure CSS and no images:

[image: How it should look like]

As you can see, its a heading with a line afterwards. The problem is, that the line should has 2 different colors and more important, 2 different heights.

- The first parts color is orange, has a height of 3px and a fixed width of 100px (padding-left: 15px)
- The sedond parts color is #E1E1E1 and should fill the rest of the line.

My first try was this:

```
<h1><span>OUR ARTICLES</span></h1>
<style>
    h1 {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    h1 span {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    h1 span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        top: 45%;
        width: 999px;
        background: #E1E1E1;
        border-left: 100px solid orange;
        left: 100%;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/oyxmxoLs/

But as you can see, I can't make the orange part thicker than the grey one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using `:before` and `:after`

http://jsfiddle.net/oyxmxoLs/1/

```css
h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
h1 span:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    top: 45%;
    width: 999px;
    background: #E1E1E1;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
h1 span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    top: 45%;
    width: 100px;
    background: orange;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top:-1px; 
}
```

```html
<h1><span>OUR ARTICLES</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution will work in IE9 as well and you answered it 2 minutes before purag!

Answer (score 5):

## Another way: Flexbox

With `display: flex` you don't have to give the line a certain width and you can make sure it is always responsive.

*We are going here with an progressive enhancement approach. We'll make a cut after IE8 by using `::before` instead of `:before`. In IE9 only the grey line will be shown (underneath the title).*

```css
h1 {
  align-items: center;
  color: #444;
  display: flex;
  font: 18px/1.3 sans-serif;
  margin: 18px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1::before {
  background-color: orange;
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  order: 2;
  width: 100px;
}

h1::after {
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  order: 3;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Our articles</h1>
```

Do **not** forget to add [vendor-prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)!

Comment: Well done! Was going to post an alternative but this is best.

Comment: Always depends on browser support. IE still lags when it comes to flexbox http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Yeah, I'm still thinking about a fallback for IE9 (e.g. not showing the orange part).

Comment: Thank you! You got a +1. But I will use the solution of wf4, because I need full IE9 support.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `:before` pseudo-element to add the orange line.

```css
h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
h1 span:after, h1 span:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    top: 45%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
h1 span:after {
    width: 999px;
    background: #E1E1E1;
}
h1 span:before {
    height: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>OUR ARTICLES</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! You got +1, but wf4 was a little bit faster!